# Check whether checkbox question with multiple answers is correct using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a html form that has a checkbox question where the correct answer is having two certain check boxes ticked. I want to use PHP to check whether the user has the correct answer and increment score variable by 1 (I know how to do the score part, but not how to check whether they have the right answer.) How can I do it?

This is the HTML for the checkbox question, the correct answer is text and images.:

```
<label >What was Mosiac capable of displaying together?:
<input type="checkbox" name="question3" id="q3answer1" value ="answer1" checked="checked" />Videos
<input type="checkbox" name="question3" id="q3answer2" value ="answer2" />Text
<input type="checkbox" name="question3" id="q3answer3" value ="answer3" />Images</label>
```

Comment: Start by giving the checkboxes an unique name like you did the `id` or maybe make them into an array like `name="question3[]"`

Comment: The thing to remember is that UnChecked checkboxes do not get sent to the PHP so to know what is checked you have to look at which checkboxes exist in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` array

Comment: Have you tried anything? This should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying but I really just don't understand how to do it. I'm a total noob. @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Someone gave you an answer below.

Comment: @Wah.P Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged both PHP and JavaScript, I will provide a solution for both languages. I'll start with JavaScript:

```js
let correct = 0;
function submitAnswer() {
   if (document.getElementById("q3answer1").checked == false && 
       document.getElementById("q3answer2").checked == true && 
       document.getElementById("q3answer3").checked == true)
   {
     correct++;
     alert("Correct!");
   }
}
```

```html
<label>What was Mosaic capable of displaying together?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="question3" id="q3answer1" value="answer1" checked="checked" />Videos
<input type="checkbox" name="question3" id="q3answer2" value="answer2" />Text
<input type="checkbox" name="question3" id="q3answer3" value="answer3" />Images
<button onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit</button>
```

Now for PHP. First, since each checkbox has the same `name` attribute, you have to assign the `name` attribute as an array. Next, all you have to do is see if the checkboxes are checked by seeing if the POST request of each checkbox is set, making sure indexes 1 and 2 are checked since they would be the 2nd and 3rd checkboxes, while also making sure the first checkbox is not checked. The following code worked for me on http://phpfiddle.org:

```
<form method="post">
   <label>What was Mosaic capable of displaying together?</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="question3[0]" id="q3answer1" value="answer1" checked="checked" />Videos
   <input type="checkbox" name="question3[1]" id="q3answer2" value="answer2" />Text
   <input type="checkbox" name="question3[2]" id="q3answer3" value="answer3" />Images
   <button name="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
  $correct = 0;
  if (isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
  {
      $checkedBoxes = $_POST['question3'];
      if (!empty($checkedBoxes))
      {
         if (!isset($checkedBoxes[0]) && isset($checkedBoxes[1]) && isset($checkedBoxes[2]))
         {
             $correct++;
             echo "<h3>Correct!</h3>";
         }
      }
      else
      {
         echo "<h3>Please select a checkbox.</h3>";
      }
  }
?>
```